# Get child item view of recyclerView in api 19

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

After searching about how to access child of recyclerview in a fragment I found below code:

```
    recyclerViewMenuItems.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> addNewVenueItem = recyclerViewMenuItems.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(2).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMenuItem), 50);
            recyclerViewMenuItems.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
        }
    });
```

so, this part of code work correctly, BUT!
the problem is when i want to find another child, I use this code :

```
    recyclerViewMenuItems.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> addNewVenueItem = recyclerViewMenuItems.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(2).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMenuItem), 50);
            recyclerViewMenuItems.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> storeItem = recyclerViewMenuItems.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(7).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMenuItem), 50);
            recyclerViewMenuItems.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        }
    });
```

every things is OK in android api level 26, But in api 19 device `storeItem` that is second view to find it, returns null!

how can I access to childs view of recyclerview (not only on child, more than one child view is the question)

Comment: The code you've posted is really odd. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @BenP. findview child of recyclerView in a getViewTreeObserver listener

Comment: No, that's what the code you've posted does. What do you actually want to do? What's the thing you're trying to do that makes you think you need to access a child of a recyclerview?

Comment: @BenP. I want to access to 2 item of recyclerView, because I want to use TapTargetView (a toolTip library for showing specific view) for those in parent activity.